# Dynamic css layout

Tags: css

I am just wondering if there is a technique to style a website in such a that my content area dynamically adjusts it's width?

The scenario is that I have 2 sidebars and 1 central content area. If one of the sidebars is missing, I would like the content area takeup the extra space left by the abscent sidebar.
And if both sidebars are missing, I would like the content area to fully expand.

I know %s can be a potential solution but I don't know how I might setup the dynamic expanding / contracting features I discribed above.

Comment: You would have to use Javascript/JQuery for that

Comment: Can you provide some code so applied answer can be given?

Comment: What does your mark-up look like? I have a possible answer, but it depends on the html you have to make it work with.

Comment: Are the sidebars fixed widths?

Comment: Hi and thanks for responding. For the purposes of those requesting markup, please visit http://www.plotsandhouses.com/search-results?province= . That link shows one sidebar and the content area. I hope that is sufficient :-)

Comment: We're currently looking at Responsive Website Design techniques that have simplified our web app using the CSS media queries combined with a fluid web design format. See http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Comment: @sisko, while code is always useful it's even more-so when the code is present here on Stackoverflow; that way the code is still available (so long as Stackoverflow's available) to those seeking answers in future. ***Please*** consider paring your mark-up down to a representative sample (taking a cue from my own abridged demo-mark-up, perhaps) and post that here in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The only CSS-only solution I could think of makes the following assumptions:

1. Your users are using up-to-date browsers, supporting the adjacent-sibling selector.
2. Your right-column appears **before** the main-content column.

The approach, demonstrated below, works using pure css, however it also uses jQuery to effect the removal (from the DOM) and recreation (in the DOM) of the right-column: jQuery ***does not*** affect/effect the styling, or dimensions, of any content (though it does also toggle the text in the link by which the column is removed/recreated).

That said, demonstration html mark-up is below:

```
<div id="contentWrap">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <!-- navigation -->
    </div>
    <div id="rightColumnAndMainContent">
        <div id="rightColumn">
            <h2>References</h2>
            <!-- a list of links -->
        </div>
        <div id="mainContent">
            <p><!-- Lorem ipsum text in the demo... --></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p><a href="#" class="remove">Remove the footer</a></p>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#contentWrap {
    width: 900px;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 110px;
}

#rightColumnAndMainContent {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 120px;
}

#rightColumn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #f00;
    width: 140px;
}

#mainContent {
    background-color: #ffa;
    margin-right: 0;
}

#rightColumn + #mainContent {
    margin-right: 150px;
}

#footer {
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    border-top: 6px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

This works as the adjacent-sibling selector (`#rightColumn + #mainContent` is more specific than the basic `id`-selector (`#mainContent`), which means that while the `#mainContent` has a defined `margin-right: 0;` it's overruled ***if*** the `#mainContent` immediately follows the `#rightColumn`, which it can only do if the `#rightColumn` is present in the mark-up.

This feels kludgy, but it does work (at least within the confines of the [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cKNZh/1/)).

---

References:

- [adjacent-sibling `+` CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors).
- [Adjacent-sibling selector cross-browser support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t12).

Answer (score 0):

I think [960 grid system](http://960.gs/) is your answer. Take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like [Adaptive CSS-Layouts](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/09/smart-fixes-for-fluid-layouts/).

Answer (score 0):

`display: table-cell` can easily do this. Browser support: http://caniuse.com/css-table

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/3FW6w/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftSidebar">left</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div class="rightSidebar">right</div>
</div>

.container {
    border: 2px solid #f0f;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table
}
.container > div {
    border: 2px dashed #444;
    display: table-cell
}
.leftSidebar, .rightSidebar {
    width: 80px
}
```